# pqxx reuse / reactivate a work transaction

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I want to use a pqxx::work for multiple queries AND commitments, while the *commit* function prevents me from using it again.
Here is a simple example :

```
pqxx::connection G_connexion("dbname=basetest user=usertest password=1234");
pqxx::work G_work(G_connexion);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    G_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('foo');");
    G_work.commit();//until here, no problem
    G_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('bar');"); //error, transaction already closed
    G_work.commit();
}
```

When I try to insert the 'bar' value, after the commit, I get a pqxx::usage_error : `Error executing query.  Attempt to activate transaction<READ COMMITTED> which is already closed`

How can I avoid to close the connection after I commit the changes? Can I reset G_work with a succeeding equivalent of G_work=pqxx::work(G_connexion), or other?
Also, one bad request should not crash the entire process, just the one in process (G_work still usable after a failure).

I have to keep the same variable G_Work because it will be a global variable called from lots of places in the program.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: No. As nobody seems to have an answer I am adding a database class to each class in my software, passing it through methods when needed.
An unique global transaction was too dangerous as I could not reactivate it if it failed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pqxx::work` is just a `pqxx::transaction<>` which eventually gets most of its logic from [`pqxx::transaction_base`](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/browser/trunk/src/transaction_base.cxx).

This class is not intended to serve for several transactions. Instead, it is intended for a single transaction within a try/catch block. It has a state member variable (`m_Status`) which is never reinitialized, even after a commit.

The normal pattern is:

```
{
    pqxx::work l_work(G_connexion);
    try {
        l_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('foo');");
        l_work.commit();
    } catch (const exception& e) {
        l_work.abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Arguably, libpqxx could rollback the transaction on deletion (to avoid the try/catch entirely) but it doesn't.

It seems that this doesn't fit your usage pattern as you want `G_work` to be a global variable accessible from several places in your program. Please note that pqxx::work is not the class for connection objects, but just a way to encapsulate begin/commit/rollback with C++ exceptions handling.

Nevertheless, libpqxx also allows you to execute statement outside transactions (or at least outside libpqxx-managed transactions). You should use instances of `pqxx::nontransaction` class.

```
#include "pqxx/nontransaction"

pqxx::connection G_connexion("dbname=basetest user=usertest password=1234");
pqxx::nontransaction G_work(G_connexion);

int f() {
    G_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('foo');");
    G_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('bar');");
}
```

Please note that this is equivalent to:

```
#include "pqxx/nontransaction"

pqxx::connection G_connexion("dbname=basetest user=usertest password=1234");

int f() {
    pqxx::nontransaction l_work(G_connexion);
    l_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('foo');");
    l_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('bar');");
}
```

Eventually, **nothing prevents you to manage transactions** with `pqxx::nontransaction`. This is especially true if you want [savepoints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html). I would also advise using `pqxx::nontransaction` if your transaction is meant to last beyond a function scope (e.g. at global scope).

```
#include "pqxx/nontransaction"

pqxx::connection G_connexion("dbname=basetest user=usertest password=1234");
pqxx::nontransaction G_work(G_connexion);

int f() {
    G_work.exec("begin;");
    G_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('foo');");
    G_work.exec("savepoint f_savepoint;");
    // If the statement fails, rollback to checkpoint.
    try {
        G_work.exec("insert into test.table1(nom) VALUES('bar');");
    } catch (const pqxx::sql_error& e) {
        G_work.exec("rollback to savepoint f_savepoint;");
    }
    G_work.exec("commit;");
}
```

Comment: Ok but using pqxx::nontransaction class lose the transactionnal part I want to keep. Indeed I want something like checkpoints : when the sohftware as reached some important points, it can submit/rollback, and then keep on going with the same global connection.

Comment: You can manage transactions yourself with pqxx::nontransaction. i edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok I already thought of that, even with pqxx::transaction I was able to use _exec("commit"); exec("begin")_ instead of G_work.begin(), what solves part if the problem. But still I need to be able to reset the connection in case of one failing request without reseting the software. For instance if i cannot insert a line due to some constraint, I must be able to keep going on the other actions.

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of SAVEPOINT. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html

Comment: OK ! the nontransaction class of G_work prevent the connexion to break when there is a illegal action on the base, and the rollback fits my checkpoints, that works for me.
Thanks for your help Paul