# Transactional objects in pqxx

Tags: c++, postgresql, object, libpqxx

I'm new in PostgreSQL and pqxx. I code in C++.
I've just written an exemple program. Everythig is alright but when I execute my program I see an error :

Started nontransaction while transaction still active.

Here's the code : http://pastebin.com/p8CJ6Eaz

If someone knows how to use those transactional objects please explain me. 
Greetings to all and thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Message `Started nontransaction while transaction still active` actually is not an error. `pqxx` is not designed to handle nested transactions and it can handle only one transaction at a time. You can read the details here;
[pqxx reuse / reactivate a work transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464056/pqxx-reuse-reactivate-a-work-transaction)

Your code is actually working OK provided that you commit the transaction before issuing a non-transaction sql command, So I would change;

uncomment the commit on line 49 to finish the transaction;
`W.commit();`

and change line 69 `W.exec(sql);` to non-transaction work;
`N.exec(sql);`

Hope that helps.