# how to clear a PostgreSQL database programmatically with libpqxx

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, libpqxx

For the [HelpCovid](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/) GPLv3+ project (C++17, Linux/x86-64, [Debian](https://debian.org/)/Buster, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) 11 or 12) and its [issue #27](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues/27), we want to clear all the data in a given PostgreSQL 11 (or 12) database. We have today (April 6, 2020, [git commit `2843184d9f589d51bd9`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/2843184d9f589d51bd9bc3eae391a7d9031b268a)) only tables and indexes there (see our [documentation in `DATABASE.md`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/DATABASE.md) and our [C++ file `hcv_database.cc`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/hcv_database.cc) for details).

We just want to remove every table and index (that is "every data") from a given database (initialized by our [`generate-config.py` python script](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/generate-config.py)).

We tried [several approaches](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commits/master/hcv_database.cc):

- [using `DROP DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html) with [a `pqxx::nontransaction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27019316/841108)
- using the dynamic SQL suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/154075/204015).

But so far every attempt failed.

In [commit cb982e1a57c9de81d](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/cb982e1a57c9de81dee1a8958f4a95e18217df6a) the following debug output is observed (debug messages output with `HCV_DEBUGOUT` macro in C++ contains `ΔBG!`). Running `./helpcovid --clear-database -D -T 2` after `./generate-config.py`:

```
./helpcovid[1393556]: HelpCovid cb982e1a57c9 start adding <?hcv confmsg, but --clear-database still does not work (issue#27) program arguments:
... ./helpcovid --clear-database -D -T 2
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_main.cc:573 -  !! parsed 5 program arguments
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_main.cc:884 -  !! start of ./helpcovid
 version:github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid built Mon 06 Apr 2020 08:35:00 AM MEST
... gitcommit cb982e1a57c9 start adding <?hcv confmsg, but --clear-database still does not work (issue#27)
... md5sum 7f39a5002c3afc4a6b242015a9f856bb on rimski
 at Mon Apr  6 08:35:15 2020 MEST on rimski
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_main.cc:626 -  !! loading configuration file /home/basile/.helpcovidrc
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_main.cc:632 -  !! helpcovid loaded configuration file /home/basile/.helpcovidrc
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_web.cc:76 -  !! hcv_initialize_web: weburl='http://localhost:8089/', webroot='/home/basile/helpcovid/webroot/', opensslcert='', opensslkey=''
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_web.cc:114 -  !! starting plain HTTP server using weburl http://localhost:8089/ and webroot /home/basile/helpcovid/webroot/ hcv_webserver@0x5622aefcb0d0
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_main.cc:964 -  !! helpcovid debugging enabled
./helpcovid[1393556]: ΔBG!hcv_main.cc:965▪ 00.00 s‣  helpcovid is debugging
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_main.cc:1026 -  !! helpcovid unable to write builtin pidfile /var/run/helpcovid.pid
-: Permission denied
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_database.cc:114 -  !! using 'dbname=helpcovid_db user=helpcovid_usr password=passwd1234 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432' as PostGreSQL connection string.
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_database.cc:129 -  !! hcv_initialize_database connstr=dbname=helpcovid_db user=helpcovid_usr password=passwd1234 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432
./helpcovid[1393556]: hcv_database.cc:133 -  !! hcv_initialize_database for connstr=dbname=helpcovid_db user=helpcovid_usr password=passwd1234 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 hcv_dbconn is 0x5622aefcb810
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::insufficient_privilege'
  what():  ERROR:  must be owner of database helpcovid_db

zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./helpcovid --clear-database -D -T 2
```

That HelpCovid program is supposed to be deployed using [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques. I am unhappy, for cybersecurity reasons, with the idea of running any external command (using [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), or [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) + [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) + [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) ..) at this stage to clear the database.

Of course I am a PostgreSQL newbie.

Comment: "Failed" without a description is too little - as a coder you should know that. Why don't you drop and re-create the schemas?

Comment: Because I am a PostGreSQL newbie and don't know how to do that. This is *precisely* what I am asking.

Comment: Then you will find it in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropschema.html).

Comment: If everything you want to drop is owned by the same (regular) user, then look into [drop owned](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html)

Comment: Here you got the complete debugging output. Anything else is required?

Comment: I tried to add everything relevant. What is missing in the improved question?

Comment: You either need to run DROP DATABASE as *database owner* or to run DROP SCHEMA as *schema owner* (of course you could also use a superuser account if really needed).

Comment: But these notions are the ones I don't understand. Any URLs? I thought a database connection has a single PostGreSQL user, defined at connection time.

Comment: Either run `drop schema ... cascade` as pifor suggested, or if you have multiple schemas and everything is owned by the same user, use `drop owned`

Comment: Please make than an answer with URL to documentation. Thanks

Comment: The name of the product is either PostgreSQL or simply Postgres. There is no capital G in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

#### `drop schema`

If everything is stored in a single schema and that schema is owned by your user, then use `drop schema ... cascade`. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropschema.html) for details.

Note that the `public` schema is typically owned by the superuser `postgres`. You will need to [transfer the ownership](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterschema.html) for that before you can do this.

#### `drop owned`

If everything(!) you want to drop is owned by the current user, you can use `drop owned ..`.

This will really drop **everything** (include views, functions, triggers, schemas, types, really: **everything**) that is owned by the user you specify.

Typically you would connect as the owner then run `drop owned by current_user;`.

See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html) for details

Comment: I don't explicitly create any schema.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: then you are probably using the `public` schema. I would go for `drop owned` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The database owner is the user that has run CREATE DATABASE: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/manage-ag-createdb.html

The schema owner is the user that has run CREATE SCHEMA:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CREATE

A database has different user accounts (just like you have different users on Linux):
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createrole.html

The user connecting from the application to the database is usually different from the database owner and from the schema owner (just like on Linux root is the admin. user but you don't use it most of the time unless you are system administrator).